# not worked upload video file via php

Tags: php, forms, video, upload

htm code :

```
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">   
 Movie :<br />
 <input name="fileField" type="file" size="30" /><br />
 <input name="submit" type="submit" class="submit" value="Send" />
 </form>
```

php code :

```
if ($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'] !=""){

            $fileName = $_FILES["fileField"]["name"];
            $fileType = $_FILES["fileField"]["type"];
            $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["fileField"]["tmp_name"];
            $fileName = preg_replace('#[^a-z.0-9]#i', '', $fileName);
            move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, '../upload/video.flv');
        }
```

this code not work for VIDEO file but work correct for other file ( jpeg , mp3 , png and ,,, )

Comment: How big is the file you are trying? Make sure your PHP settings [support uploading large files](http://www.sitepoint.com/upload-large-files-in-php/)

Comment: thanks aam1r, php setting set to 2MB size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps change your directory to
     `move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, '../upload/ ');`

Answer (score 0):

this problem from php setting
php set to Max 2MB size for upload

Answer (score 0):

You have absolutely no error handling on the code, meaning you have no way of telling when an upload failed. Add:

```
if ($_FILES['fileField']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   die("Upload failed with error " . $_FILES['fileField']['error']);
}
```

as some bare-minimum error handling. The error codes are defined here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php. Checking for the absence of a 'tmp_name' is NOT a proper check.